# I want to add stopwatch in a fragment but the app crashes on clicking the image buttons. how to resolve?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I wanted to add Stopwatch in a fragment with bottom navigation activity. I got no error at all but the app crashes on onclicking the image buttons I have created for start pause and reset. Please Help!

```
package com.example.chatapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class StopwatchFragment extends Fragment {
    private boolean running;
    private long pauseoffset;
    private Chronometer chronometer;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable
            Bundle savedInstanceState ){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stopwatch, null);
        chronometer = view.findViewById(R.id.cm);
        return view;
    }
    public void startcm (View view){
        if (!running){
            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseoffset);
            chronometer.start();
            running = true;
        }
    }

    public void pausecm (View view){
        if (running){
            chronometer.stop();
            pauseoffset = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
            running = false;
        }
    }

    public void resetcm (View view){
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        pauseoffset = 0;
    }
}
```

This is my java code of that fragment. Android Studio shows no error in this.

But here in my xml code of that fragment. In front of onclick it shows

1. cannot resolve symbol name "startcm"
2. cannot resolve symbol name "pausecm"
3. cannot resolve symbol name "restartcm"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StopwatchFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_stopwatch"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_stopwatch"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/cm"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bold"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_button"
        android:tint="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:onClick="startcm"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:fontFamily="@font/regular"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pause_black_24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_button"
        android:tint="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:onClick="pausecm"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pause"
        android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="157dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:fontFamily="@font/regular"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/restart"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_button"
        android:tint="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
        android:onClick="resetcm"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reset"
        android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="258dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:fontFamily="@font/regular"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The xml `onClick` tag looks for your functions in your *Activity*, not in your fragment. Probably 3 solutions:

- Move these functions to your Activity
- Add `view.findViewById(R.id.cmstart).setOnClickListener()` to your fragment, and remove the xml tag.
- You might can add a reference to your fragment in the xml tag, but I don't know how by heart.